# How to make wordpress Dynamic Search-Bar from Predesigned Static Html Search-Bar?

Tags: search

I am converting my static HTML code into dynamic WordPress theme. In my `header.php` there is already been coded for a Search-Bar which have nice look & feel. Code block looks like this:

```
<div id="search">
  <div class="button-search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." onfocus="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

What if I want to use exactly this search-bar to be converted into dynamic search bar without changing it's CSS.

I mean I don't want to use wordpress's default function of Search-Bar (form) `get_search_form()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty easy to make our static HTML Search-Bar dynamic.

*First,* wrap up our `<input />`tag with `<form> </form>` tag mentioning `action=""` and `mehotd=""`

*Second,* **identify** the default **key** of wordpress and **assign** it in `name=""` attribute of input tag.

To be specific, the code would be like this:

```
<form method="GET" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>">
    <input name="s"placeholder="Search..." />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**How to identify:** we may use `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` in header.php (just for a temporary test) to get the default search-bar of wordpress so that we can search any word in it. Let, we search with a word (post) written in search bar. Then we will get the result with all post words written, if we look at the address bar we are supposed to see like this: your_website.com/?s=new

So, **s** & *new* is the **key**/*value* pair identified.

Hope it helps.